# Browser not sending jsession id with requests

Tags: spring, angular, spring-boot

I am writing an Angular4 app with Spring Boot backend. I am using a SessionScoped bean to store the logged in user (I know this is not RESTful and stuff and I am ok with it for now) and RestControllers for the endpoints.

Logging in and querying data with Postman works nicely, but it does not work from my angular app, so I debugged it a little and saw that I get jsessionid-s in the response-headers, but they are not appended in the requests.

What might be the problem? How can I use Angular with Spring Boot and session scoped beans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how your are calling the backend.
If you are using angular-cli and the proxying the calls to spring boot it should work out of the box since same domain requests always pass cookies.

This is the preferred way because usually this is how you then deploy it live using a nginx location block to get all /api/ calls go to spring and everything else to angular.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md

If you have the api on a different host you will need to pass `withCredentials: true` to all requests going to the backend to force the request to include the cookies.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials

`this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/thing', { withCredentials: true }).subscribe()`